# compiler errors when initializing EXPECT_CALL with function which has program_options::variables_map as parameter

Tags: c++, boost, googlemock

I'm having a problem with EXPECT_CALL method, when trying to do this :

```
boost::program_options::variables_map vm;  
MyMock mock;  
EXPECT_CALL(mock, MyMethod(vm)).WillOnce(Return(L""));
```

MyMethod looks like this :

```
std::wstring MyMethod(const boost::program_options::variables_map &vm)
```

When compiling I got errors :

```
Error   17  error C2676: binary '==' : 'const boost::program_options::variable_value' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility   

Error   10  error C2784: 'bool std::operator ==(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'const boost::program_options::variable_value'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility
```

And a few more similar errors.

Comment: Is `boost::program_options::variables_map` copyable?

Comment: I think so, as I can do something like this:  
    boost::program_options::variables_map vm1;  
    vm1 = vm;

Comment: @Als But is seems that there is no "==" operator.  I cannot do this if(vm1 == vm) {do something}. If I try this, I have the same errors as above.

Comment: Looks like it is not assignable then, I am not sure if it is meant to be that way, I have not used it before.I asked since the error and if it might ring a bell to you.

Comment: It is strange then I can even call method myObject->MyMethod(vm)...

Comment: @Als No, the problem is lack of operator== for boost::program_options::variables_map

Comment: @VJovic: Yes, The error explicitly says so actually. I didn't understand the *No*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use EXPECT_CALL, your class needs to support `operator==`. Since `boost::program_options::variables_map` has no `operator==`, you can not use it like that.

You could [define you own matcher](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Defining_Matchers) for `boost::program_options::variables_map`, however I would advise you to [pass it to a function](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Using_a_Function_or_a_Functor_as_an_Action) where you would check expected values (or you can ignore, set flag, or do whatever you please). Something like this :

```
int called = 0;
void foo( const boost::program_options::variables_map &)
{
  ++ called;
}
```

In the test :

```
boost::program_options::variables_map vm;  
MyMock mock;
called = 0;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, MyMethod(_)).WillOnce(Invoke(&foo));  
// assert that called is 1
```

Comment: It is possible to do this :  
`EXPECT_CALL(mock, MyMethod(_)).WillOnce(Invoke(&foo));`
But the problem is that I have two functions MyMethod with different parameters, so I cannot use "_" in my calls, because it is ambigous call...

Comment: @user1160721 Right. That's what I meant. Your question doesn't mention the 2nd method

Comment: You can disambiguate the type of the expected parameter with a wildcard matcher: http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can create your own predicate as a matcher as I've found I've needed to do when trying to match with boost.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Using_Predicates_as_Matchers).

In your test:

```
using :testing::Return;
using ::testing::Truly;
EXPECT_CALL( object , connectSlot( Truly( PredicateFunc ) ) ).Times( 1 ).WillOnce(Return( boost::signals::connection() ) );
```

while you have a function (or functor)

```
bool PredicateFunc( boost::signal0<void>::slot_type const& slot )
{
    /* Custom matcher code */
    return true | false;
}
```